# Javascript & jquery | I want to get the text in the <span> tag outside the button the user clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery, getvalue

[Web site picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezUMI.png)

Hello I want to get a val in span with on click event but **I must use one event for this.**

What am I trying to do basicly if user click PAY button inside in second div I should get

.faturatarih value witch is "09-05-2021 10:22" in second div but

if user click PAY button in first div I should get "09-05-2021 08:22"

sorry for my bad english

Here is my HTML code

```
<div class="fatura">
    <span class="faturaTarih">09-05-2021 08:22</span>
    <button type="button" class="faturaOdeButton">PAY</button>
    <p class="faturaGonderenIsım">Mr. Jack</p>
    <span class="faturaAciklama">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae, minus provident.</span>
    <span class="faturaDurum">Waiting</span><span class="faturaUcret">$500,00</span>
</div>
<div class="fatura">
    <span class="faturaTarih">09-05-2021 10:22</span>
    <button type="button" class="faturaOdeButton">PAY</button>
    <p class="faturaGonderenIsım">Mr. Tom</p>
    <span class="faturaAciklama">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae, minus provident.</span>
    <span class="faturaDurum">Waiting</span><span class="faturaUcret">$1000,00</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Try : `$(".faturaOdeButton").on("click", function() {console.log($(this).prev().text())})`

Comment: Its worked thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this:

```
$(".faturaOdeButton").on("click", function()
{

// Get date
 var date = $(this).closest(".fatura").find(".faturaTarih").text();
 
 // For test
 alert(date)
 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a javascript function that uses the `event` parameter to reference its elements. Replace all of your `<button type="button" class="faturaOdeButton">PAY</button>` with `<button type="button" class="faturaOdeButton" onclick="pay(event)">PAY</button>` (or just simply add the `onclick` attribute. Then, in your JavaScript, you can define the function:

```
function pay(e){
    var value = e.target.parentElement.querySelector(".faturaTarih").textContent;
    console.log(value);
}
```

The above code will receive the event parameter, then find the `target`, or the element the "ping" was sent from. Then, it will get its parent element and find all of the elements inside it with the class list of `faturaTarih`(which should only be one). It will get the textContent of that element and display it in the console.

Comment: my problem is solved thank you very much for explaning the code

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getData(clicked_id){

 let id = clicked_id;

if(id == "button1")
{
let value = document.getElementsByClassName("faturaTarih")[0].innerText;
console.log(value)
}

if(id == "button2")
{
let value = document.getElementsByClassName("faturaTarih")[1].innerText;
console.log(value)
}

}
```

```html
 <div class="fatura">
                    <span class="faturaTarih">09-05-2021 08:22</span>
                    <button type="button" class="faturaOdeButton">PAY</button>
                    <p class="faturaGonderenIsım">Mr. Jack</p>
                    <span class="faturaAciklama">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae, minus provident.</span>
                    <span class="faturaDurum">Waiting</span><span class="faturaUcret">$500,00</span>
                </div>
                <div class="fatura">
                    <span class="faturaTarih">09-05-2021 10:22</span>
                    <button type="button" class="faturaOdeButton">PAY</button>
                    <p class="faturaGonderenIsım">Mr. Tom</p>
                    <span class="faturaAciklama">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae, minus provident.</span>
                    <span class="faturaDurum">Waiting</span><span class="faturaUcret">$1000,00</span>
                </div>
```

Comment: its not what am I trying to exactly but thank you my problem is solved